Extract from nested JSON in SQL
I have a json col in a table along with an id:



id
json_col




abc123
json_text



json value is as below:
[
  {
    "type": 0,
    "isPro": true,
    "addOns": [
      {
        "cod": "DAIRY_PLAN",
        "base": 0,
        "type": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 140,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 2,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      },
      {
        "cod": "HW12-201809",
        "base": 0,
        "type": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 99,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 1,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      },
      {
        "cod": "HW_BAND_E",
        "base": 0,
        "type": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 40,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 3,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      },
      {
        "cod": "HW_LEVEL_3",
        "base": 279,
        "type": 1,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 100,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 4,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": 1,
    "isPro": true,
    "addOns": [
      {
        "cod": "HW12-FW",
        "base": 0,
        "type": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 99.3333,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 1,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      },
      {
        "cod": "HW_BAND_SHEEP_A",
        "base": 0,
        "type": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 3,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      },
      {
        "cod": "HW_LEVEL_2",
        "base": 99.33,
        "type": 1,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 50,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 4,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      },
      {
        "cod": "SHEEP_PLAN",
        "base": 0,
        "type": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 2,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": 2,
    "isPro": true,
    "addOns": [
      {
        "cod": "CROP_PLAN",
        "base": 0,
        "type": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 2,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      },
      {
        "cod": "CW_BAND_G",
        "base": 0,
        "type": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 120,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 3,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      },
      {
        "cod": "HW12-CROP",
        "base": 0,
        "type": 0,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 99,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 1,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      },
      {
        "cod": "HW_LEVEL_1",
        "base": 219,
        "type": 1,
        "count": 1,
        "price": 0,
        "goodsType": null,
        "typeAddOn": 4,
        "goodRelatedId": null
      }
    ]
  }
]

I want to extract each nested object and arrive at:



id
item1_name
item2_name
item3_name
item4_name
item1_price
item2_price
item3_price
item4_price




abc123
json_text[0].addons[0].cod
json_text[0].addons[1].cod
json_text[0].addons[2].cod
json_text[0].addons[3].cod
json_text[0].addons[0].price
json_text[0].addons[1].price
json_text[0].addons[2].price
json_text[0].addons[3].price



Tried a few ways to access it but without explicitly entering a subscript number im unable to get all values using *
e.g.
with 
explode_array as (
select json_query(json_col,'lax $[*].addOns'  ) as array_items from get_inner_json
)


select * from explode_array

but it just throws null? but when i check the docs it seems like it should work? https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#array-accessor
Any ideas on how to tackle this?
Im using aws athena (trino) so ANSI SQL

Trino does not support dynamic flattening/pivoting, so if you want separate columns then you will need to create them manually. json_extract/json_extract_scalar will work:
select json_extract(json_col, '$[0].addOns[0].cod'),
    json_extract(json_col, '$[0].addOns[1].cod'),
    json_extract(json_col, '$[0].addOns[2].cod'),
    json_extract(json_col, '$[0].addOns[3].cod'),
    json_extract(json_col, '$[0].addOns[0].price'),
    json_extract(json_col, '$[0].addOns[1].price'),
    json_extract(json_col, '$[0].addOns[2].price'),
    json_extract(json_col, '$[0].addOns[3].price')
from dataset;

Output:



_col0
_col1
_col2
_col3
_col4
_col5
_col6
_col7




"DAIRY_PLAN"
"HW12-201809"
"HW_BAND_E"
"HW_LEVEL_3"
140
99
40
100



Otherwise you need to use arrays. Note that you have array in array, so you need to use double wildcards:
select json_query(json_col,'lax $[*].addOns[*].cod' with array wrapper) names, -- use lax $[*].addOns[*] to get whole JSON object
    json_query(json_col,'lax $[*].addOns[*].price' with array wrapper) prices
from dataset;

Output:



names
prices




["DAIRY_PLAN","HW12-201809","HW_BAND_E","HW_LEVEL_3","HW12-FW","HW_BAND_SHEEP_A","HW_LEVEL_2","SHEEP_PLAN","CROP_PLAN","CW_BAND_G","HW12-CROP","HW_LEVEL_1"]
[140,99,40,100,99.3333,0,50,0,0,120,99,0]




the second wildcard + with array wrapper did the trick! what would teh  fundamental difference be between with array wrapper and without? is it that without can be used only for scalar outputs?

@darkCoffy Was gald to help! Basically yes, it will consider only a scalar outputs.
